# Poor quality image when restart the application

Tags: android, image, picasso, image-quality

In the app there is an item add an avatar in your account, when you add it - the picture is filled to the server and displayed as expected:

Good

[image]

But if i do restart the application, then image quality is lost:

Bad

[image]

When comparing the weight and size of the image between what was covered on the original server and all is fine, the weight and size is identical. Displaying an avatar comes directly from the server. What could be the problem?

Caching is missing, use Picasso. Code to display avatars:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(link).into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you call

```
Picasso.with (context) 
    .load (link) 
    .fit()
    .into(imageView);
```

it works

Comment: It could be helpful to explain why resize is possibly needed.

Comment: Correction. Icreated a test and changed resize() by fit()

With resize() the image lost the resolution, but with fit() it was excellent. 

Maybe when resizing the image with resize() the picasso does not make the adjustment by adding the dpi